# How to align the first line of the equation to the left?

Tags: equations, align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
\det\bigg(\lambda I -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\bigg) 
\\
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
A(G_2)\otimes Q(G_1) \otimes I_{n_2} &&  G^T
 \\
 G &&
A(G_1)\otimes Q(G_2)\otimes I_{n_1}
\end{array}
\right].
\end{flalign*}    
\end{document}
```

I am stuck at the following code.
I want the the first line i.e.

```
\det\bigg(\lambda I -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\bigg)
```

to start from the left of the document.
But the problem is the first line is aligned to the right of the document which is making it look weird.

Is it possible to align everything to the left of the document?

Please help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\det\biggl(\lambda I -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\biggr)    
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
A(G_2)\otimes Q(G_1) \otimes I_{n_2} 
    &  G^T  \\
G   & A(G_1)\otimes Q(G_2)\otimes I_{n_1}
        \end{bmatrix}.
    \end{align*}
or with use of the \verb+\MoveEqLeft+ defined in the \verb+mathtools+ package:
    \begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[4]\det\Bigl(\lambda I -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\Bigr)    \\
    & = \begin{bmatrix}
A(G_2)\otimes Q(G_1) \otimes I_{n_2}
    &  G^T  \\
G   & A(G_1)\otimes Q(G_2)\otimes I_{n_1}
        \end{bmatrix}.
    \end{align*}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why align everything left ? I would recommend using `multline`here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\det\bigg(\lambda I -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\bigg)\\
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
A(G_2)\otimes Q(G_1) \otimes I_{n_2} &  G^T \\
 G & A(G_1)\otimes Q(G_2)\otimes I_{n_1}
\end{array}
\right].
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You only have to declare in the code at least two alignment columns. The flalign environment doesn't align on the left automagically.

I took the liberty to simplify your code: as I didn't see why an array with 20 columns – I replaced it with the  simpler `bmatrix`  environment. I also didn't see why the huge parentheses for the argument of `\det`, so I replaced the pair `\bigg( ... \bigg)` with `\bigl( ... \bigr)` (note the final l and r).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\det\bigl(\lambda I & -ABC(G_1\circ G_2)\bigr) & &
\\[0.5ex]
 & =
\begin{bmatrix}
A(G_2)\otimes Q(G_1) \otimes I_{n_2} && G^T
 \\[1ex]
 G &&
A(G_1)\otimes Q(G_2)\otimes I_{n_1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]